# Unreal Engine Blueprint: how to move actor along spline?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

In my game there is an Actor implemented in a Blueprint. On each level instance of this actor must move along some path. On different levels the paths are different.

How to implement this behavior?

If I add Spline component to this Blueprint then the path will be identical on all levels. But I need different paths. Maybe there is an ability to add a reference to another actor in the current level? But I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWXI91FdMtk) solution? You can always keep actor reference in spline(new spline on each level instance) or create "SplineManager" bp to deal with reference update.